# unable to start activity from service class

Tags: java, android, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

Please be informed, we are trying to start activity from service class, which is fired on clicking push notification addaction intent. The service class contains two actions, one to stop playing ringtone and another to startactivity. But unfortunately the start activity just does not boot in our service class.

Service Class page is as given below:

```
public class RingtonePlayingService extends Service {
    private static final String TAG = RingtonePlayingService.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final String URI_BASE = RingtonePlayingService.class.getName() + ".";
    public static final String ACTION_DISMISS = URI_BASE + "ACTION_DISMISS";
    public static final String ACTION_START = URI_BASE + "ACTION_START";

    private MediaPlayer mp;
    private Ringtone ringtone;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onStartCommand");
        int notificationId = intent.getIntExtra("notificationId", 0);

        if (intent == null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "The intent is null.");
            return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
        }

        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (ACTION_START.equals(action)) {

            String uri = String.valueOf(intent.getIntExtra("uri", 0));
            Intent intents = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            intents.putExtra("uri", uri);
            intents.putExtra("notification_id", notificationId);
            intents.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            this.startActivity(intents);
        }
        

        return START_STICKY;
    }

            @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mp.reset ();
    }}
```

Firebase (from where service class's intent is fired)

```
Intent startIntent = new Intent(this, RingtonePlayingService.class);
startIntent.setAction(RingtonePlayingService.ACTION_START);
startIntent.putExtra("uri", uri);
startIntent.putExtra("notification_id", notification_id);
PendingIntent pt = PendingIntent.getService(this,123, startIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);



NotificationCompat.Action action_n = new NotificationCompat.Action.Builder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher, tag, pt).build();
```

The objective here is on firing of pending Intent 'pt'. We want to start the activity (that opens the app's url) as well as run the service class (which stops the service and the ringtone).

Please help us find a solution on this never ending issue.

Answer (score 0):

> The service class contains two actions, one to stop playing ringtone and another to startactivity. But unfortunately the start activity just does not boot in our service class.

You [cannot start an activity from the background](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts) on modern versions of Android.

> Firebase (from where service class's intent is fired)

That code has problems:

- Your `Intent` is for `RingtonePlayingService`, which according to your first code snippet is a `Service`. Yet, you try using it with `PendingIntent.getActivity()`, rather than `PendingIntent.getService()`.
- You are using `addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK)`, which are irrelevant for a `Service`.

Comment: Edited the code, added some explanation. Please check.

Comment: Since we cannot start the activity from service class, is it possible we can stack two pending intents (firing service class and start new activity) inside one intent.

Comment: @Ahamed: "We want to start the activity (that opens the app's url) as well as run the service class (which stops the service and the ringtone)" -- an activity can stop a service, and an activity can work with ringtones. You do not need a service for that. So, you only need one `PendingIntent`, to start your activity. "is it possible we can stack two pending intents (firing service class and start new activity) inside one intent" -- no.

Comment: Can we start an activity in broadcast receiver.

Comment: @Ahamed: No, because a receiver is not usually in the foreground. Start your activity from your notification's `PendingIntent`, and have the activity do whatever else is necessary.

Comment: Sorry, if i'm wrong doing this. But can you just help on associated issue that could possibly enable me to avoid using service class: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73923427/mediaplayer-stop-causes-android-app-to-crash