# mediaplayer.stop causes android app to crash

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

In our andorid broadcaster receiver class, we are trying to stop the ringtone that's initiated from mainactivity.class. We used mediaplayer.stop to stop the ringtone, which it successfully does, but it crashes the app. We have used .stop (), .pause (), .release (), but none of them is working unfortunately.  The codes of broadcastreceiver is as given hereunder

Firebase class (summarized code) where media player is initialized and pending broadcast intent to buttonreceiver class is fired where mediaplayer is stopped.

```
public class Firebase extends FirebaseMessagingService {
            public static Ringtone ringtone;
            public static MediaPlayer mp;

Intent buttonIntent = new Intent(this, ButtonReceiver.class);
buttonIntent.putExtra("notificationId",notification_id);
PendingIntent btsPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, requestID, buttonIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
NotificationCompat.Action action1 = new NotificationCompat.Action.Builder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher, "Dismiss", btsPendingIntent).build();

NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, MainActivity.asw_fcm_channel)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle(title)
                    .setContentText(message)
                    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                    .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                    .setTimeoutAfter(60000)
                    .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_CALL)
                    .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
                    .setAutoCancel(false)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .addAction(action1)
                    .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
                    .setFullScreenIntent(pendingIntent2, true)
                    .setVibrate(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400});
        
                mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, Settings.System.DEFAULT_RINGTONE_URI);
                mp.start();
        }
```

Button Receiver Class (where media player is stopped)
public class ButtonReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
public MediaPlayer mp;

```
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        int notificationId = intent.getIntExtra("notificationId", 0);

    
        mp.stop ();
        mp.seekTo(0);

        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        manager.cancel(notificationId);

    }
}
```

Please help us out on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't show MediaPlayer being initialized, so it would definitely crash as soon as you try to reference the `mp` instance.

I'm pretty sure that you misunderstood how `MediaPlayer` works. It's not a global service -- you have to manage each instance yourself. Based on your code, you're instantiating it twice in different places, and expecting them to somehow control the same instance. You're declaring and creating the `MediaPlayer`, and starting playback in your `FirebaseMessagingService` class, but you're trying to stop it in your `BroadcastReceiver` class. But there, you're trying to use a totally different instance of `MediaPlayer`, which has never been initialized, and that's why it's crashing.

You'll need to keep a global reference to your `mp` object (either in a singleton, or in your Application object), and change the rest of your code to use it properly. For example:

```
 public class App extends Application {
        public static MediaPlayer mp;
    }

public class Firebase extends FirebaseMessagingService {
   ...

   if(App.mp == null){
        App.mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, Settings.System.DEFAULT_RINGTONE_URI);
   }
   App.mp.start();

   ....
}
```

and in your Broadcast Receiver:

```
if(App.mp != null){
        App.mp.stop ();
        App.mp = null
   }
```

Comment: added more code, please check

Comment: I still don't see any connection between where your media player gets initialized and where you try to stop it. The two pieces of code are completely disconnected from what you posted

Comment: added more explanation